# How to start AsyncTask from another class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would like to execute the doInBackground() method of AsyncTask inner class of my ArticleListFragment_develop.class from another class.  How would i go about doing this. Please can someone help me with the syntax? I have tried a few things and i keep getting errors.

```
  public class ArticleListFragment_develop extends ListFragment { 

   ........
  private class DownloadXmlTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Article>> {
    /*
     * @Override protected void onPreExecute() { pDialog = new
     * ProgressDialog(getActivity());
     * pDialog.setMessage("Loading search results...");
     * pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
     * pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false); pDialog.show(); }
     */
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Article> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Log.d(TAG, "DownLoadXmlTask Thread id: "
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        try {
            return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return articles;
    }
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried, and what the errors are.  From a quick glance the DownloadXmlTask should be static and any methods it calls (e.g. loadXmlFromNetwork) should be contained within it or static methods as well.  Ideally it should be in it's own class if you are using it in multiple fragments/activities.

Comment: i"m getting red underlined marks:

Comment: result = ArticleListFragment_develop.DownloadXmlTask.execute(arg)

Comment: Async task execute will not return you articles array, read article under link. This is multithreading, you dont know when the result will be.

Comment: Remember to check answer that helped you, this is how you show that some answear was usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Write the AsyncTask in a seperate class file and use it.

```
new DownloadXmlTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

[First read this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) Then you have to have OBJECT of your async task. Write public method in your class that will be executing async task and call it. Caller object have to have reference to your fragment object.

Comment: normally i would call the doInBackground method as follows :

Comment: new DownLoadXmlTask.execute(arg).......but when I am outside of this class, i do not know how to call it

Comment: I wrote you how to do it "Write public method in your class that will be executing async task and call it.". Maybe you are not familiar in basic Java language syntax. Remove this -1 and start learning, I'll report your downvoting.

Comment: but i just increased it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is that the inner class AsyncTask is not visible to any other class.
My suggestion is either bring the AsyncTask out of the ArticleListFragment_develop class, or create a function and call it from outside classes.

Comment: Could you provide a working example of what you mean?